# Encrypt selected data only in Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts, synchronization, crm

Is there a way to have let's say an online CRM platform sync its contact details in realtime with Google Contacts, but hide the contact's phone numbers or encrypt them for certain users of the CRM based on their role/permissions, but while still allowing them to *add* new contacts with their phone numbers?